# how to display negative exponent as superscript?

Tags: octave

I wish to create a 2-D plot with x-axis values:  `0, 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1, 10^2`.
I tried using semilog(x), but that does not work because the 0-value gets dropped (understandably).

So instead I am using xticklabels

```
datalabels = {'0', '10^-2', '10^-1', '10^0', '10^1', '10^2'};
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
plot(data);
set(gca(),"xticklabel", datalabels);
```

This is working fine, except for one small nit:
The x-axis labels get displayed differently, depending on whether the exponent is positive or negative.  Positive exponents are displayed as superscripts.  Negative exponents are not.  For example, '10^-2' is displayed as '10-2', with '-2' sitting on the same baseline as '10'.

Anyone know how to enforce consistency, so all the exponents are displayed as superscripts?

UPDATE:  I created a legend with a mixture of negative and positive exponents, and it looks *really* ugly.  I now see that, in addition to inconsistently displaying the exponent as a superscript, Octave uses different fontsizes, depending on whether the exponent is negative or positive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried `'10^{-2}'`

From [this reference](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_172.html):

> Finally, the superscript and subscripting can be controlled with the
>   '^' and '*' characters. If the '^' or '*' is followed by a {
>   character, then all of the block surrounded by the { } pair is super-
>   or sub-scripted. Without the { } pair, only the character immediately
>   following the '^' or '_' is super- or sub-scripted.

Comment: Unfortunately, you may now get '10^0' to display the 0 exponent (it probably didn't when it was a number).

Comment: Hahaha:  I tried parens and square brackets so, of course, it was CURLY brackets.  ‍♂️